# How to quote the not supported substring URL in python

Tags: python, url, unicode, web-scraping

Following is the URL :

> [https://www.siasat.pk/forum/showthread.php?553205-قطری-ہو-یا-برطانوی-خط-کرپشن-کی-نشانی-ہے&s=be8abfc34aa0ca5ddf9b6d40b2acad4b&p=4505464#post4505464](https://www.siasat.pk/forum/showthread.php?553205-%D9%82%D8%B7%D8%B1%DB%8C-%DB%81%D9%88-%DB%8C%D8%A7-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%B7%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%88%DB%8C-%D8%AE%D8%B7-%DA%A9%D8%B1%D9%BE%D8%B4%D9%86-%DA%A9%DB%8C-%D9%86%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%86%DB%8C-%DB%81%DB%92&s=be8abfc34aa0ca5ddf9b6d40b2acad4b&p=4505464#post4505464)

`req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})`

If i try to `urlopen(req)` it gives exception as 
[image]

I want to convert the characters to make it valid URL, how to get that substring and convert to valid utf 8  from `quote`

If i try to to quote(url) complete one, it will make it invalid.

Comment: "it will make it invalid" - what do you mean? `urllib.parse.quote(req)` is doing exactly what you need.

Comment: i want to make the substring to complete utf 8 though quote in order to make open url.

Comment: Have tried adding `u'...'` if you're working in 2.X?

Comment: Did you actually try `urlopen(quote(req))`?

Comment: @direprobs i am using python 3

Comment: @DYZ actually when i try this, it convert all the URL and end i get exception as unknown url type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extarct the query part and quote just that part:

```
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, urlunsplit, quote
url_split = urlsplit(url)
query = quote(url_split.query)
url_quoted = urlunsplit(url_split._replace(query=query))
# 'https://www.siasat.pk/forum/showthread.php?553205-%D9%82%D8%B7%D8%B1%DB%8C-...'
```